# Choose variable type at runtime through config file

Tags: c++, type-conversion, runtime

I have seen answers that deal with choosing a variable type, dynamically, at runtime([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11196851/c-variable-type-selection-at-runtime), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735796/is-it-possible-to-choose-a-c-generic-type-parameter-at-runtime), and links from there on), but, even if some may go a bit over my head (fairly new to C++), is there a way to read the variable type from a config file and use it during runtime?

For example, the config may have `type=double` as a line, and can be changed to `type=long double` through the settings of the program, and use that variable type without restarting the application.

---

I need to calculate the roots of some polynomials. Some, even of they have small orders, need large precision, and if they get to high orders, they need even greater. Still, I can do away with `double` or `long double` for small enough numbers, but as I get higher, I need MPFRC++ (which is what I am sing, currently). I'd like to avoid the slowing down (even if it's not that noticeable for smaller orders) bu being able to use high precision only when needed.

Comment: Simple answer: No.

Comment: All variable types used in a c++ program are determined and instantiated at compile time. May be you could link some of these answers, and we can explain what's done there.

Comment: Maybe you can use if else like  if(type=="double")   double var; else if.....

Comment: @NathanOliver Then no it is, thank you for the answer. Though I don't think the downvoting is an incentive for beginners in C++. To knowledgeable people, the answer may be obvious, to me it isn't.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen OK, so let's say you could change the data type at runtime.  What exactly are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: Well I am not the down voter so I cannot help you there.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen You should also note such thing as you describe is possible using interfaces and a Factory Pattern, but not for primitive types.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Suppose I have to run a function that deals with arrays of anty size. For smaller sizes, there isn't that much need of precision, it can get away with `double`, or `long double`, but when the elements get larger than, say 50, then greater precision is needed. Currently I am using MPFRC++ for all, and it can be "felt" for lower lengths.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Then, considering the minor edit, the answer is the same as with NathanOlivier?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Your question still is extremely unclear and broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you may be could use is a [*Factory Pattern*](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method/cpp/1) along with the [*Strategy Pattern*](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy) and an appropriate interface. Something along the lines:

```
struct IPolyRootSolver {
    virtual PolyRoot calcRoot(const Polynom& poly) const = 0;
    virtual ~IPolyRootSolver () {}
};

class DoublePolyRootSolver : public IPolyRootSolver {
public:
    PolyRoot calcRoot(const Polynom& poly) {
        // Implementation based on double precision
    }
};

class LongDoublePolyRootSolver : public IPolyRootSolver {
public:
    PolyRoot calcRoot(const Polynom& poly) {
        // Implementation based on long double precision
    }
};

class MPFRCPolyRootSolver : public IPolyRootSolver {
public:
    PolyRoot calcRoot(const Polynom& poly) {
        // Implementation based on MPFRC++ precision
    }
};
```

---

```
class RootSolverFactory {
public:
    RootSolverFactory(const std::string configFile) {
         // Read config file and install a mechanism to watch for changes
    }

    std::unique_ptr<IPolyRootSolver> getConfiguredPolyRootSolver() {

         if(config file contains type = double) {
             return make_unique<IPolyRootSolver>(new DoublePolyRootSolver());
         }
         else if(config file contains type = long double) {
             return make_unique<IPolyRootSolver>(new LongDoublePolyRootSolver());
         }
         else if(config file contains type = MPFRC) {
             return make_unique<IPolyRootSolver>(new MPFRCPolyRootSolver ());
         }
         else {
             // Handle the default case
         }
};
```

I hope you get what I mean.

---

As mentioned in comments you can also use *free standing functions* from a namespace instead of the above mentioned abstract interface solution:

```
namespace PolyRootDoublePrecision {
    PolyRoot calcRoot(const Polynom&);
}

namespace PolyRootLongDoublePrecision {
    PolyRoot calcRoot(const Polynom&);
}

namespace PolyRootMPFRCPrecision {
    PolyRoot calcRoot(const Polynom&);
}

class RootSolverFactory {
public:
    RootSolverFactory(const std::string configFile) {
         // Read config file and install a mechanism to watch for changes
    }

    std::function<PolyRoot (const Polynom&)> getConfiguredPolyRootSolver() {

         if(config file contains type = double) {
             return std::function<PolyRoot (const Polynom&)>
                         (PolyRootDoublePrecision::calcRoot);
         }
         else if(config file contains type = long double) {
             return std::function<PolyRoot (const Polynom&)>
                         (PolyRootLongDoublePrecision::calcRoot);
         }
         else if(config file contains type = MPFRC) {
             return std::function<PolyRoot (const Polynom&)>
                         (PolyRootMPFRCPrecision::calcRoot);
         }
         else {
             // Handle the default case
         }
};
```

---

Aside from using a configuration file, you could consider to select the strategy to use from other criteria as a configuration file.

E.g. for your case it seems the complexity (i.e. number of sub terms) of the polynomial expression plays an essential role for selecting the best strategy to use. So you can write some code like

```
    std::function<PolyRoot (const Polynom&)> getPolyRootSolver(const Polynom& polynom) {

         if(polynom.complexity() < 7) {
             return std::function<PolyRoot (const Polynom&)>
                         (PolyRootDoublePrecision::calcRoot);
         }
         else if(polynom.complexity() >= 7 &&
                 polynom.complexity() < 50) {
             return std::function<PolyRoot (const Polynom&)>
                         (PolyRootLongDoublePrecision::calcRoot);
         }
         else if(polynom.complexity() >= 50) {
             return std::function<PolyRoot (const Polynom&)>
                         (PolyRootMPFRCPrecision::calcRoot);
         }
};
```

Comment: I think this compliments the other answers just fine. I already have the root solver as a namespace, but it can easily be transformed. Only, it's fairly large, and it may come at a cost in code size. I'm sorry about the fuzzyness of my question, but, to try to be a bit more clear about the scope, what I have in mind is http://www.linear.com/designtools/software/#LTspice. You can add `.opt numdgt=7` and anything `>=7` will use `double` instead of `float`, so I was wondering if the same can't be done with a config, since my program is only used for polynomials&co.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Another way to simplify the factory (without the interface), is using `std::function<Poly (const Polynom&)>` as return type of the `getConfiguredPolyRootSolver()` function, if you already have free standing functions in a namespace.

Comment: It's a good answer and, for the beginner me, it proves to be a good starting point, so I marked this as the answer.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I've updated my answer for more coverage of the _broadness_.

Comment: The last part looks much better suited, indeed. It will still need 3 times as much code, but maybe I can get away by not reusing all the helper functions, just maybe. The more I look at it, the more it seems the best choice. My current way involves passing a variable precision for the MPFRC++ root finding, something like `64+8*N`, it varies on the type of polynomial. But root finding is not the only thing I do, that's why I wanted to use native formats as much as precision allows. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen De nada. I also think the _complexity_ is an inherent property of the polynomial, and should be determined from that, rather than using a configuration file. But hopefully you see the flexibility of the _Factory Pattern_ or the _Abstract Factory Pattern_. You should just decouple the specific implementation of a strategy from it's usage and selection criteria.